# Calculate text width on iOS given UIView

Tags: android, ios, text-rendering

In Windows world you can do this to get text width:

```
SIZE size;
GetTextExtentPoint(DC, "hello", strlen("hello"), &size)
printf("x = %i y = %i\n", size.x, size.y);
    // will print x = 30, y = 15 (for instance)
```

How can I easily do that on iOS, provided that I have UIView handle on hand?

Comment: It would better fit StackOverflow's paradigm if you asked two separate questions (one for iOS and one for Android) so that an answer could be accepted for each. Someone else looking up this question in the future might only be interested in one of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iOS (I'll let someone more knowledgeable in Android development answer the second part), you'll want to use a variant of [`sizeWithFont:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont%3a). Depending on whether or not you wish to allow multiple lines you should check out the various methods explained in the documentation I linked.

The one I typically find most useful is [`sizeWithFont:constainedToSize:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont%3aconstrainedToSize%3a) where I set the constrained size to have the limited width that I have available in a view, and the height to `CGFLOAT_MAX`, which allows the label to use up as much vertical space as needed (since I often have labels within vertically scrolling views).

Comment: These have been deprecated! Their new equivalents are  [sizeWithAttributes:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1531844-sizewithattributes?language=objc), and [boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1524729-boundingrectwithsize?language=objc)